# Equivalence of Sobolev Norms via Fourier Transformation

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, fourier-transform

I am working through a proof which shows that the usual Sobolev norm $\|\cdot\|_{k,2}$ on $W^{k,2}(\Omega)$ is equivalent to the norm

$$
\|u\|_{H^m} := \| (1 + |\cdot|^2)^{\frac{k}{2}}\mathcal{F}u \|_2
$$

At one point we use the inequality

$$
2^{-k} \leq \frac{1 + |\xi|^{2k}}{(1 + |\xi|^2)^k} \leq 2.
$$

Since the fraction always is smaller than one, the right inequality is not a problem. 
But I can't find a way to prove the left inequality.
Is there an elementary proof to this inequality?

Comment: $\|f\|^2_{W^{k,2}} = \sum_{|m|\le k} \|\partial_m f\|^2_{L^2} = \sum_{|m|\le k}  \|\ |\xi|^m \hat{f}\|^2_{L^2} \sim\|\ (1+|\xi|)^{k} \hat{f}\|^2_{L^2}$ (where $\sim$ means the two norms are obviously equivalent)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Distinguish the cases $|\xi|\leq 1$ and $|\xi|> 1$ and use crude bounds.

Comment: Nice. Thanks a lot.